# Washer tray AND stand pipe with trap?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, remodeling

I am moving my washer and dryer up to my second floor.  I plan on using a tray with a floor mounted shower type drain.  Will there be enough room in the joist bay below to join the tray drain and the stand pipe first AND use a p-trap?  Do they make a special joint for this?

Comment: Oh, I see now with code, apparently the stand pipe trap has to be in the wall, not below the floor.  If I have to use a separate trap for the tray drain, it will dry out.  So this is not doable is it?

Comment: It is an issue with overflow tray and floor drain traps that they dry out. That does not make them non-doable. It only means some occasional maintenance is required in the form of running water into the traps once in a while. Better than having an overflow ruining a good part of your house.